# Warning while moving Mailitem from draft to Custom Folder on click of send

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Scenario: Suppose there is a MailItem in the Drafts , I open it and click on Send button.

Item_Send is manipulated to move the mailitems to a custom folder

```
void Application_ItemSend(object objItem, ref bool blCancel)
        {
                Outlook.MailItem mailItem = objItem as Outlook.MailItem;
                if (mailItem != null)
                {
                    if (mailItem.Mileage != null)
                    {
                        blCancel = true;
                        string folderPath =
                          Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder().FolderPath
                          + Utilities.OUTBOXPATH;
                        Outlook.Folder folder = GetFolder(folderPath);
                        if (folder != null)
                        {
                            mailItem.Move(folder);
                        }
                    }
                }

        }
```

Now the MailItem moves to the New Folder ItemAdd Event

```
private void OutboxItems_ItemAdd(object objItem)
{
        if (objItem is MailItem)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = objItem as Outlook.MailItem;

            if (mailItem != null)
            {
                (mailItem as _MailItem).Send();
            }
        }
}
```

But in between It Outlook gives a warning as
**The Attempted Operation Failed. An object can not be found.**

Can anyone please tell what can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be moving message that Outlook is trying to send. You can instead set the MailItem.SaveSentMessageFolder property - after the message is actually sent, Outlook will move the message there.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for replying.

Comment: I have to stop the mail from sending and do some manipulation first by moving it to a intermediate folder.

Comment: Try to move the message after you are out of the event handler - save the item entry id a variable, enable a timer in the ItemSend callback, when the timer fires (you will be out of the event handler by then), disable the timer, open the message using Namespace.GetItemfromID, then move it.